# Looking for a better solution - long list of AND operator with a type String comparision

Tags: mysql, sql

I have search function which does search for keywords in an large mysql table, but since i need to filter out all the bad words, i have to do a following type of a AND comparison in the MySQL, which is a long list of banned words (over 500+) , due to this its very slow,

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE 1  
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%love%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%hope%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%caring%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%x%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%happiness%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%forgiveness%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%good%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%great%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%positive%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%sharing%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%awesome%'
    AND keyword NOT LIKE '%fantastic%'
```

any other better way of doing this ?

Comment: You could do this with a regexp check... I'm not sure about the performance difference.

Comment: regexp is very slow, i can do NOT IN but problem is i cant use the %% with that, i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LIKE` pattern-matching has terrible performance, because there's no way to use an index for it.  Using regular expressions like @fuzic suggests is even worse.

You really need to use some fulltext indexing solution if you want good performance.

I cover this and compare several solutions in my presentation, [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

---

The brief answer:  use [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: Hi Bill, love you book. I agree with your statements about LIKE and RegExp being a bad solution. Would you mind suggesting a better solution for OP here though?

Comment: excellent .. i tried your myisam with full text solution with natural language it reduce the query time from 5.0s to 0.3 s ... however if i add ORDER BY RAND(), OR GROUP BY it again goes back to 2.8s. I can work around GROUP BY using DISTINCT keyword but there is no solution for RAND() problem, any idea on that ? BTW, the innodb solution using full text didnt work it think its still experimental for innodb....

Answer (score 0):

You could do worse than to build a Finite State Machine that recognizes the complete set of strings. Coding one by hand would be tedious, but fortunately tools  such as LEX, and its descendants and kin, have been around for nearly 40 years to automate that process.